# how to update nested object using mongoose nodeJS and axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update the property date which is inside the object remindTime.
here is the original data

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "614d3cedfb2600340fdb28f9"
    },
    "date": "2021-09-23",
    "title": "First test",
    "description": "Going",
    "remindTime": {
        "date": "2021-09-23",
        "time": "11:50:09 pm"
    },
    "isComplete": false,
    "instantMessage": false,
    "owner": "wxTWH8zqSwaIXPAVsjZoRCkvjx73",
    "uuid": "0E561203-0BD0-4E15-AB17-858FFBD972D9",
    "createdAt": {
        "_delegate": {
            "_methodName": "FieldValue.serverTimestamp"
        }
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

axios request data coming in on req.query = { _ref: '1632545954ref', owner: 'wxTWH8zqSwaIXPAVsjZoRCkvjx73' }
axios request data coming in on req.body = { remindTime: { date: '2021-09-28' } }

```
Templates.updateMany((req.query, req.body))
    .then(
      (record) => {
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        res.json(record);
      },
      (err) => res.status(400).json(err)
    )
```

Here is the output but not what I desire

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "614d3cedfb2600340fdb28f9"
    },
    "date": "2021-09-23",
    "title": "First test",
    "description": "Going",
    "remindTime": {
        "date": "2021-09-24"
    },
    "isComplete": false,
    "instantMessage": false,
    "owner": "wxTWH8zqSwaIXPAVsjZoRCkvjx73",
    "uuid": "0E561203-0BD0-4E15-AB17-858FFBD972D9",
    "createdAt": {
        "_delegate": {
            "_methodName": "FieldValue.serverTimestamp"
        }
    },
    "_ref": "1632545954ref",
    "__v": 0
}
```

As you can see that the property date in remindTime was updated however it erased the time property

I am hoping to only update the date property and keep the time property as is like shown below but with updated date

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "614d3cedfb2600340fdb28f9"
    },
    "date": "2021-09-23",
    "title": "First test",
    "description": "Going",
    "remindTime": {
        "date": "2021-09-28",
        "time": "11:50:09 pm"
    },
    "isComplete": false,
    "instantMessage": false,
    "owner": "wxTWH8zqSwaIXPAVsjZoRCkvjx73",
    "uuid": "0E561203-0BD0-4E15-AB17-858FFBD972D9",
    "createdAt": {
        "_delegate": {
            "_methodName": "FieldValue.serverTimestamp"
        }
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$set` operator to update your date property exclusively, without loosing other fields.

```
req.body = { remindTime: { $set: { date: '2021-09-28' } } }
```

You can check below links for more detailed info:

[MongoDB $set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/set/#mongodb-pipeline-pipe.-set)

[updateMany opertors](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/#parameters)